# foreach in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having some problems to make the following code to work in my side bar of wordpress:

```
            $the_query = get_posts( $args );


            $year_post = 0;
            foreach ($the_query as $post) : 
                setup_postdata($post);
                $current_year = get_the_time('Y'); 
                if( $current_year != $year_post ) {
                    $year_post = $current_year;
                    echo '<li><a href="'.get_year_link($current_year).'">'.$current_year.'</a></li>';
                }
                $month_post = 0;
                foreach ($post as $post_monthly) : 
                       setup_postdata($post_monthly);  
                       $current_month = get_the_time('m');
                        if ($current_month != $month_post){
                               $month_post =$current_month;
                               echo '<li><a href="'.get_year_link($current_month).'">'.$current_month.'</a></li>';
                        }

                        foreach ($post_monthly as $post_title) : 
                                setup_postdata($post_title);

                                echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.the_title().'</a></li>';
                        endforeach;

                endforeach;

            endforeach;

            wp_reset_postdata();
```

With this code I am trying to display the following:

- 2012
  -May

  - Lorem ipsum
  - Lorem ipsum
  - Lorem ipsum

It display 2012, May, but when it comes to display the titles of the post I am getting the following  error: "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() "

I have checked so many times this code, I just don't seem to see the problem.

Can anyone see something that I am missing, It will be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `get_posts()` is an array of objects. So then, your `$post` contains an object, not an array.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Answer (score 2):

You should check if `$post_monthly` and `$post_title` are actually arrays. You could do that by using [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).

It is quite possible that in some month, there are no posts, then the value of variable might be `null` (i am not an expert in wordpress, but that's what would explain the error message). You could mitigate it by having a condition with [`!empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) or [`is_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) before the loop.

Answer (score 2):

add the (array) before $arrays:

```
foreach ((array)$post...
```

to ignore empty ones and warnings like this

Answer (score 2):

for Example:

```
<?php   

    $args = array(

    'post_type' => 'art',

    'post_status' => 'publish',

    'posts_per_page' => -1,

    ); ?>
    <?php $my_posts = get_posts( $args );

    foreach($my_posts as $my_post){ ?>
    <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($my_post->ID),array(500,500)); ?>
        <div class="view_list">
        <div class="flt1 ">  <img src="<?php print $image[0]; ?> "></div>   

        <ul>
            <li> <? echo  $my_post->post_title; ?> </li>
            <li> <? echo the_time('l, F j, Y'); ?> </li>
            <?php $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $my_post->ID, array( 'act', 'subject' ) ); ?>
            <? // print_r ( $terms); ?>

            <img src="<?php echo $url[0]; ?>"  alt="" />
            <li><?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) : ?>
            <? $term_link = get_term_link( $term ); ?>
            <?php //echo $term->taxonomy; ?><a href="<? echo $term_link  ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a> 
            <?php endforeach; ?></li>   
            <?php echo get_field('Height', $my_post->ID) .'*' .get_field('width', $my_post->ID) ;  ?></li>
        </ul>

        </div>  <? }?>
```